# Reduce the number of active threads created by ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

For a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I want to monitor the number of threads which are actually running. But it seems that this is impossible. The number of active threads is continually increasing. For normal thread, if the target function returns, the thread will shutdown.

```
import threading, concurrent.futures

def test():
    pass

p_ac=threading.active_count()
#Number of threads=2

#for threads
trs=[None]*10
for i in range(10):
    trs[i]=threading.Thread(target=test)
    trs[i].start

print(threading.active_count()==p_ac)
#True

#for executor
executor=concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
for _ in range(10):
    executor.submit(test)
print(threading.active_count())
#Number of threads=12
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` **does not** shutdown its threads when active. `ThreadPoolExecutor(X)` creates `X` threads and keeps them alive until you shutdown the executor via `executor.shutdown()` or the executor itself decides it doesn't need so many threads. Anyway `X` is the expected amount of threads if the executor is active.

Comment: So can I keep track of the the number of threads that are actually running? My purpose is to choose an optimized number of max_workers. Currently I'm using a global counter to do that (i.e. +1 when submitting the function and -1 when the function returns).

Comment: @user2923419 You don't have to keep track of the number of threads when you are using `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You can safely assume that there are as many threads as you've defined. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: So I think there is difference between setting max_workers to 10 and setting it to 100, right? I don't want to generate extra threads if they cannot help improve efficiency.

Comment: @user2923419 10 max_workers means 10 threads. 100 means 100 threads. Just play around with different values and measure the performance.